# Add a line through buttons with php, using SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a database "test" the rows are username, category and testnr.
I want to use php to cross out any buttons/links on my website that user A has already done. For example username: userA finished testnr:1, so the link test1 in category A gets a line through. The following is as far as I got- (I am sorry, I am a beginner).
However, it would be terribly inefficient. I would have to "if" call for every category and, more annoyingly, testnr in each category. I also would need a next $text everytime, since otherwise every button would be crossed off.
There has to be a better way to do it, but I can not think of anything.

```
$curuser = $membersite->UserName();
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE user='$curuser'";
$text = "";

if ( !mysqli_query( $con,$sql ) ) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
$results = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $results ) ) {
   $category = $row['category'];
   $tnr = $row['testnr'];
   if( $category = "Categname" && $tnr = 1 ) {
       $text="style='text-decoration:line-through'";
   }
 }
mysqli_close( $con );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your if case!!!
change this

```
if( $category = "Categname" && $tnr = 1 ) {
```

to

```
if( $category == "Categname" && $tnr == 1 ) {
```

You are assigning the values instead of checking!!! thats why all the links get line-through. See this [ref](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)